# How my NPM front end library (bundled) can detect if used in development mode or production mode?

Tags: javascript, development-environment, nodeenv

I am author for an NPM library of browser web components and I wish to alert users that a new version has been released. Library is developed in VueJs.

Since it is not a cli, I cannot use the `update-notifier` package as is since the lib code is not executed at installation or build - at least could not find any hook to do this.

So I am trying to detect if my users are executing my library in their development environment or in their production environment.
If they are in development I will look for new version and print a message in their console panel.

What I have done is to use the `process.env.NODE_ENV` in my library, but when bundled with webpack it get replaced by `"production"`, so my user will always have a code with production...

How can I get their `process.env.NODE_ENV`?

If I construct code that bypass webpack (such as an `eval("process.env.NODE_ENV")` it wont work because the process object does not exists at run time in the browser.
Also, I cannot rely on Angular `isDevMode()` since my users may well be using another framework or no framework at all (pure html).

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you not ship separate production / development builds?

Comment: @Keith, no I ship a single version because I cannot ask/force users to use one or the other. Unless I am missing a best practice. Could you then clarify?